# After Effects render on AWS EC2

Tags: after-effects, animation-rendering

I want to render my After Effects projects on an EC2 Windows AMI for better performance, but they only allow Windows Server editions which are no supported by Adobe. Will it work if I install After Effects on Windows Server 2008? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server is very much the same as the Desktop Windows regarding the core of the OS, there is just some stuff missing and other stuff added that is usefull for webservers.

You shouldn't have any problems installing an After Effects render node, I used Windows Server 2008 R2 myself for an After Effects CS5 network render node.
Shouldn't have changed with newer versions of After Effects.